# Can't understand shape(output) = (shape(value) - ksize + 1) / strides in TensorFlow docs

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

In the following excerpt from http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn.md#pooling

shape(output) = (shape(value) - ksize + 1) / strides

where the rounding direction depends on padding:

- padding = 'SAME': Round down (only full size windows are considered).
- padding = 'VALID': Round up (partial windows are included).

I can't understand the formula above. I am familiar with following formula though:

shape(out) = (shape(value) - ksize + 2*pad)/strides+1.

Are the two formulas equivalent?

For example, let's say shape(value) = 9, ksize = 3, strides = 2, and padding = 'SAME'.

In the first formula the shape(output) will be (9-3+1)/2 = 7/2 = 3.5 and rounding down results in 3.

In the second formula the shape(output) will be (9-3+2*1)/2 + 1 = 5

It doesn't seem to be the same formula. Even if I round up the first one, the result will be 4.

In addition to that, the padding definition seems to be inverted. Isn't the 'SAME' padding that includes partial windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem. The two formulas become equivalent if you assume that the appropriate padding is already included in shape(value). But I still think the definition of the padding types have been swapped in the documentation. I created an issue to report that: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/196

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer and get +25 points.